# Multiprocessing and variable return?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have been banging my head against Multiprocessing in Python for the better part of the day now, and I've managed to make very little progress - I apologize if my question is a duplicate or my ignorance is apparent - I couldn't find it asked anywhere else in this way.

I'm looking for a way to run functions in parallel, and return some arbitrary thing they've produced back to the main script.

The question is:  Can a Process() started from Multiprocessing return a list or some other arbitrary variable type?

For example, I would like to:

```
def 30_second_function():
    #pretend this takes 30 seconds to run
    return ["mango", "habanero", "salsa"]
#End 30_second_function()

def 5_second_function():
    #pretend this takes 5 seconds to run
    return {"beans": "8 oz", "tomato paste": "16 oz"}
#End 5_second_function()

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=30_second_function)
p1.start()
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=5_second_function)
p2.start()

#Somehow retrieve the list and the dictionary here.  p1.returned??
```

And then somehow access the list from 30_second_function and the dictionary from 5_second_function.  Is this possible?  Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Process` itself does not provide a way to get return value.  [To exchange data between processes, you need to use queue, pipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes), shared memory, ...:

```
import multiprocessing

def thirty_second_function(q):
    q.put(["mango", "habanero", "salsa"])

def five_second_function(q):
    q.put({"beans": "8 oz", "tomato paste": "16 oz"})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q1 = multiprocessing.Queue()
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=thirty_second_function, args=(q1,))
    p1.start()

    q2 = multiprocessing.Queue()
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=five_second_function, args=(q2,))
    p2.start()

    print(q1.get())
    print(q2.get())
```

Alternative using [`multiprocessing.pool.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool):

```
import multiprocessing.pool

def thirty_second_function():
    return ["mango", "habanero", "salsa"]

def five_second_function():
    return {"beans": "8 oz", "tomato paste": "16 oz"}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.pool.Pool()
    p1 = p.apply_async(thirty_second_function)
    p2 = p.apply_async(five_second_function)

    print(p1.get())
    print(p2.get())
```

Or using [`concurrent.futures` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures) ([also available in standard library since Python 3.2+](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)):

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def thirty_second_function():
    return ["mango", "habanero", "salsa"]

def five_second_function():
    return {"beans": "8 oz", "tomato paste": "16 oz"}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as e:
        p1 = e.submit(thirty_second_function)
        p2 = e.submit(five_second_function)
    print(p1.result())
    print(p2.result())
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed - I'm not sure why I didn't understand this from the documentation, but your example here has really helped.  I can't wait to try it.

Off topic - do you know why the args=(q1,) needs that seemingly rogue comma to function properly?

Comment: @Locane, without a trailing comma, it beccame `(q1)` which is equal to `q1`. You can use list form instead: `[q1]` if you don't like it.

Comment: @Locane, You're right. The trailing comma is there to denote that, it's a tuple literal. BTW, it also accepts a list.

Comment: @senderle, I forgot it. Thank you for reminding it. I updated the answer to add it.

Comment: Falsetru in your Pools example (which is what I ended up using) can you please mention that object functions don't work properly?  IE, self.gather_data called in the pool will not work, but gather_data will.  This was a "gotcha" that was not obvious to me until I experimented with it.

Comment: @Locane, How about post your finding as a separate question-answer, or update your question to include your problem regarding method (object function?)?